# Uneven thickness around an oval Blender

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I have been trying to create an oval that has an even thickness around it. This feels fairly simple and I don't know why I can't figure it out.

When I make a mesh->circle->scale circle to be an oval and then go into modifier-> solidify->increase thickness (click even thickness) I can tell that the oval isn't evenly thickness

[image][image]

any suggestions?

Comment: have you applied the scale in Object mode?

Comment: i scale it in object mode then apply the modifier, is this wrong?

Comment: don't apply the modifier, apply the scale if you've scaled your object in Object mode, to apply the scale press Ctrl A

Comment: ahhh thank you!